# How to group nodes with relationships in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, grouping

I have the following table which lists related nodes:

```
;WITH CTE AS
( SELECT *
  FROM (VALUES (1,2)
              ,(2,1)
              ,(3,4)
              ,(3,5)
              ,(4,3)
              ,(4,5)
              ,(5,3)
              ,(5,4)
              ,(6,NULL)
              ,(7,NULL)
              ,(8,9)
              ,(9,8)
        ) AS ValuesTable(ID,RelatedID)
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
```

How can I assign unique IDS (GUID or integer GroupID) to each group, So, 1 and 2 will be on the same group, 3, 4, 5 on a different group, 6 is alone in it's group and so is 7, and 8 and 9 are one more group?

My answer so far seems very cumbersome:

```
;WITH CTE AS
( SELECT *
  FROM (VALUES (1,2)
              ,(2,1)
              ,(3,4)
              ,(3,5)
              ,(4,3)
              ,(4,5)
              ,(5,3)
              ,(5,4)
              ,(6,NULL)
              ,(7,NULL)
              ,(8,9)
              ,(9,8)
        ) AS ValuesTable(ID,RelatedID)
)
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY CA.IDList) AS GroupID,
       ID,
       RelatedID
FROM CTE
CROSS APPLY (SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255), ID)
             FROM CTE AS CTEInner
             WHERE CTEInner.ID = CTE.ID
                OR CTEInner.ID = CTE.RelatedID
                OR CTEInner.RelatedID = CTE.RelatedID
                OR CTEInner.RelatedID = CTE.ID
             FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'') AS IDList) AS CA
```

But it provides the correct answer:

```
GroupID ID  RelatedID
1   1   2
1   2   1
2   3   4
2   3   5
2   4   3
2   4   5
2   5   3
2   5   4
3   6   NULL
4   7   NULL
5   8   9
5   9   8
```

Comment: I am sure there is something more complex required than just using the NewID() function (Assumed sql server due to tsql tag) - can you show us what the expected result is at least? (A non-cycle tree walk to collate the groups?)

Comment: So, 1 and 2 will be on the same group, 3, 4, 5 on a different group, 6 is alone in it's group and so is 7, and 8 and 9 are one more group, is that correct?

Comment: @Zohar, Yes, thats correct

Comment: @Andrew i think its less complex than that. The groups are separated. Every ID in each group is Related to every other ID within the group.

Comment: Does it have to be a guid? Because I can show you how to add a unique number for each group, but adding a guid will make it more cumbersome.

Comment: Unique number also works for me! Thanks for your help. Problem appears simple on surface, but i can't wrap my head around it!

Answer (score 2):

Adding a unique number for each group is not hard but it does require a few steps.

The first step would be to select unique values for the groups - so for instance the group with `(1, 2)` and `(2, 1)` will contain only a single record - `(1, 2)`.

The next step is to get rid of the records that creates multiple paths for the same relationship - in this case - `(3, 4), (4, 5), (3, 5)` - means that `5` is the related to both `3` and `4`, but for the recursive cte to work, we only need a single relationship path - so either `(3, 4), (4, 5)` or `(3, 4), (3, 5)` but not both.

The next step is to create a recursive cte based on these unique values, so that each group can get it's unique number.

After that, you can select from the original cte joined to the recursive cte and get the unique group numbers:

```
;WITH CTE AS
( SELECT *
  FROM (VALUES (1,2)
              ,(2,1)
              ,(3,4)
              ,(3,5)
              ,(4,3)
              ,(4,5)
              ,(5,3)
              ,(5,4)
              ,(6,NULL)
              ,(7,NULL)
              ,(8,9)
              ,(9,8)
        ) AS ValuesTable(ID,RelatedID)
)
, PreUniqueValues AS
(
    SELECT  MIN(ID) AS ID, 
            MAX(RelatedID) As RelatedID
    FROM CTE AS B
    GROUP BY (ID + ISNULL(RelatedID, 0)) + (ID * ISNULL(RelatedID, 0))
)
, UniqueValues AS
(
    SELECT ID, MIN(RelatedID) As RelatedID
    FROM PreUniqueValues 
    GROUP BY ID
)
, Recursive AS
(
    SELECT ID, RelatedId, DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY ID) As GroupID
    FROM UniqueValues AS T0
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1
        FROM UniqueValues AS T1
        WHERE T1.ID = T0.RelatedID
    )
    UNION ALL
    SELECT UV.ID, UV.RelatedID, GroupID
    FROM UniqueValues As UV
    JOIN Recursive As Re 
        ON UV.ID = Re.RelatedId
)

SELECT CTE.ID, CTE.RelatedID, GroupID
FROM CTE
JOIN Recursive 
    ON CTE.ID = Recursive.ID OR CTE.ID = ISNULL(Recursive.RelatedID, 0)
ORDER BY ID
```

Results:

```
ID  RelatedID   GroupID
1   2           1
2   1           1
4   3           2
4   5           2
5   3           2
5   4           2
6   NULL        3
7   NULL        4
8   9           5
9   8           5
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but shouldn't there only be 5 groups (1,2), (3,4,5), (6), (7), (8,9)

Comment: The problem is that RelatedID 5 appears both with 3 and with 4 as it's anchor. Back to the drawing board...

Comment: @DannyRancher I've edited my answer with a correct solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is a graph-walking problem and you would seem to need recursive CTEs.  The logic looks like this:

```
WITH t AS (
      SELECT *
      FROM (VALUES (1,2)
              ,(2,1)
              ,(3,4)
              ,(3,5)
              ,(4,3)
              ,(4,5)
              ,(5,3)
              ,(5,4)
              ,(6,NULL)
              ,(7,NULL)
              ,(8,9)
              ,(9,8)
        ) AS ValuesTable(ID,RelatedID)
    ),
         cte as (
          select distinct id, id as relatedId, ',' + convert(varchar(max), id) + ','  as relatedIds
          from t
          union all
          select cte.id, t.relatedId,  cte.relatedIds + convert(varchar(max), t.relatedId) + ','
          from cte join
               t
               on cte.relatedId = t.id
          where cte.relatedId is not null and
                cte.relatedIds not like '%,' + convert(varchar(max), t.relatedId) + ',%'
         )
SELECT id, min(relatedId) as grp,
       dense_rank() over (order by min(relatedId)) as grp_number
FROM cte
GROUP BY id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=484bf65435fc542f3ee7ef29e1559aee) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Finally, this answer solved my issue as well. However, the performance can be _significantly_ improved by replacing `UNION ALL` by `UNION` only and, thus, omitting _all_ the `relatedIds` stuff: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7a1637168381dae6972d64e2c210b0b9). If so, branches/forkes are tracked only once.